# brew install php56-mongo Command Not working

Tags: php, macos, mongodb, xampp, homebrew

I'm trying to install the MongoDB PHP driver for XAMPP on my **OSX**. When I run:

```
brew install php56-mongo
```

I get the following message: **No available formula for php56-mongo**

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ brew tap homebrew/php
$ brew install php56-mongodb
```

Comment: Latest mongo driver has been renamed to php56-mongodb `brew install php56-mongodb` https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/blob/master/Formula/php56-mongodb.rb

Comment: Do you have solution for same problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40790093/i-can-not-install-mongodb-php56-osx

Answer (score 4):

Recently they have deprecated the *homebrew/php* and archived *homebrew/homebrew-php*

You can follow this repo in order to install **phpxx-extensions**
Let's say for **php71-mongodb** you can use this.

```
brew tap kyslik/php
brew install php71-mongodb
```

Bug Info: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76177

Comment: `brew tap kyslik/php` results in several errors, ending with `Error: Cannot tap kyslik/php: invalid syntax in tap!`
Is there another similar keg we can tap into?

Comment: Its updated by php. Can you tell me the output of `php -v` from your terminal.

Comment: This answer is not working as of 2020. It results in a lot of `Invalid formula`